# Strange rounding behaviour of Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I found a rounding behaviour for Javascript's Uint8ClampedArray that does not make sense to me. According to [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray), when setting non-integer to an Uint8ClampedArray "the nearest integer will be set".

The strange thing is that for any values `i+0.5` (where `i` is an integer) the values will be rounded up if `i` is odd, and rounded down if `i` is even.

Here is a simpele example to show the behaviour:

```
var clampedArr = new Uint8ClampedArray(1);
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var val = i + 0.5;
    clampedArr[0] = val;
    console.log(val + " -> " + clampedArr[0]);
}
```

The output is

```
0.5 -> 0
1.5 -> 2
2.5 -> 2
3.5 -> 4
4.5 -> 4
5.5 -> 6
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjosL7g7/) with the code above.

Can this behavior be explained somehow as it is different from `Math.round()`?

Comment: Rounding down if even and up if odd is how rounding is supposed to work. They teach that in introductory science classes in the topic on precision and accuracy.

Comment: This is expected. It prevents a bias toward rounding up.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: Thanks all, you seem to be right, but still the behavior is different from Math.round(). Is there a specific reason to use a different rounding for array values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not satisfied with the comments because they do not explain the difference to Javascript's standard rounding behavior as used by `Math.round()`. Therefore I dug a little deeper.

[Mozilla's documentation for Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) simply says "if you specify a non-integer, the nearest integer will be set", without specifying the type of rounding. Javascript programmers (as myself) would probably assume that the rounding is the same as in `Math.round()`

[Microsoft's documentation for Uint8ClampedArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/uint8clampedarray-object-javascript) is more precise and adds the following remark: **"Values in a Uint8ClampedArray object are rounded to the nearest even value, which is called banker's rounding."** This makes it clear that a rounding different from `Math.round()` is being used.